# Java Cant find Trusted Certificate (JKS)

Tags: web-services, ssl, certificate, cxf, jks

I need to consume a service using CXF and I am facing the following issue.

Even though I had my Java key store (JKS) workig o SOAP UI, for example, when I use it on my java program it always give me the message

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found
```

I have checked the JKS file and the certificate is in there, so when I put it on the SOAPUI project, it is recognized and the service successful called, with no problems. I am using as base the code provided by the cxf web site (http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/cxf/trunk/distribution/src/main/release/samples/wsdl_first_https/src/main/java/demo/hw_https/client/ClientNonSpring.java?view=log) , as follow:

```
public static void setupTLS(Object port) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, GeneralSecurityException
{
    final String keyStoreLoc = "d:/certs/mykeystore.jks";
    HTTPConduit httpConduit = (HTTPConduit) ClientProxy.getClient(port).getConduit();

    TLSClientParameters tlsCP = new TLSClientParameters();
    final String keyPassword ="password";
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(keyStoreLoc), keyPassword.toCharArray());
    KeyManager[] myKeyManagers = getKeyManagers(keyStore, keyPassword);
    tlsCP.setKeyManagers(myKeyManagers);

    KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    trustStore.load(new FileInputStream(keyStoreLoc), keyPassword.toCharArray());
    TrustManager[] myTrustStoreKeyManagers = getTrustManagers(trustStore);
    tlsCP.setTrustManagers(myTrustStoreKeyManagers);
    httpConduit.setTlsClientParameters(tlsCP);
}

private static TrustManager[] getTrustManagers(KeyStore trustStore)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException
{
    String alg = KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
    TrustManagerFactory fac = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(alg);
    fac.init(trustStore);
    return fac.getTrustManagers();
}

private static KeyManager[] getKeyManagers(KeyStore keyStore, String keyPassword)
        throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException
{
    String alg = KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
    char[] keyPass = keyPassword != null ? keyPassword.toCharArray() : null;
    KeyManagerFactory fac = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(alg);
    fac.init(keyStore, keyPass);
    return fac.getKeyManagers();
}
```

When debugging, I can see that the certs are loaded and the keystore and keystrustmanagers are populated accordingly, so after days trying to figure out what is happening, I am running out of ideas. So if you guys have any tip that can help,please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here are some tests that might help: https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cxf.git;a=blob;f=systests/transports/src/test/java/org/apache/cxf/systest/https/trust/TrustManagerTest.java;h=6264f447d87b7aad790ecec007ba69de43cab7c5;hb=HEAD

Answer (score 0):

After running some more tests it was clear that the certificate was the problem. I changed the jks for a valid one and now its running perfectly.

For the ones that need a solution like that, the example that I based my solution (http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/cxf/trunk/distribution/src/main/release/samples/wsdl_first_https/src/main/java/demo/hw_https/client/ClientNonSpring.java?view=log) works like a charm.